# Issues using random raster, possibly mismatched extent

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, map-algebra

I am very much a beginner in using ArcGIS Pro.

I have two rasters, call them Col1.tif and Col2.tif.

I want to create a new raster that randomly chooses either the value from Col1 or Col2 with 50% probability.

To do this I created a random raster. When I created it I set the extent to be the same as Col1.tif. I first tried a random raster that was uniform on [0,1],and then used map algebra expressions like: `Con( "rr.tif" ,"dblCropCol12008.tif", "dblCropCol12009.tif", "VALUE > 0.5")` This didn't work (error 99999).

Then I tried making a random raster that was either 1 or 2, and then tried to use the 'Pick' function. This also returned a 99999 error.

The issue might be the extent of the random raster. I am not sure. Although created with the same extent as Col1, they seem to misalign at the edge. See the picture below. Even when I reproject the random raster on col1 or col2, there is always something a little wrong at the edge.

[image]

Update, here is the information about each of my rasters.

[image]

Comment: Your workflow worked for me, no alignment issues. So are both your crop rasters the same extent, cell size and coordinate system? You random raster should match those.

Comment: updated! sometimes I even have trouble just creating the random raster, getting the same issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So your additional screen shots have confirmed they are same extent and cell size, the only different is the coordinate systems of your rr.tif. Try recreating the random raster but in the environment settings explicitly set it to one of your crop rasters (you can import it from one of the rasters), give that ago?

Comment: ahh yes once fixing this it worked! Thanks!